# ¿Como crear un picturebox de manera dinamica en C#?

Tags: c#, picturebox

Bueno lo que quiero hacer es la generacion de varias cajas de imagenes en mi aplicacion de C#, en pocas palabras un historial de las imagenes subidas a mi aplicacion. Actualmente tengo el siguiente codigo:

Codigo de Generacion de imagenes (No funciona).

```
    var directorio = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\Enero");
    PictureBox[] pics = new PictureBox[1000];
    for (int i=0;i<directorio.GetFiles().Length;i++) {
        pics[i] = new PictureBox();
        pics[i].Location = new Point(50,50);
        pics[i].Name = "pic" + i;
        pics[i].Size = new Size(300, 75);
        pics[i].ImageLocation = @"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\Enero\Enero0.jpg";
    }
```

El codigo de arriba en teoria deberia de crearme las imagenes, en este caso 3 imagenes en su picturebox, se que se emplamaria porque estarian del mismo tamaño y en la misma ubicacion, eso pienso modificarlo, pero por el momento no me genera ni una sola imagen, el winforms donde se deberian generar sale en gris sin nada y esas instrucciones estan en el constructor del winform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recuerda que debes agregar la instancia del `PictureBox` a la colección del `form`:

```
var directorio = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"..\..\Imagenes\Imagenes_Modal\Usuario\Enero");

foreach (var file in directorio.GetFiles()) 
{
    PictureBox pic = new PictureBox();
    pic.Location = new Point(50,50);
    pic.Name = "pic" + i;
    pic.Size = new Size(300, 75);
    pic.ImageLocation = file;

    this.Controls.Add(pic);
}
```

En la última línea el `this` ser al mismo form donde se agrega el control, si quieres hacerlo contra un `Panel` u otro control también puedes.

Además no necesitas un `array` de `PictureBox`, puedes ir creándolas y agregándolas al `form`.